# How to save cookies with selenium firefoxdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, cookies, tabs, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have an automated test that uses multiple tabs.

I need to open multiple tabs and interact with the content on the pages. 
To interact with these tabs i need to be logged in to the service.

Normally on my own browser i log in at the front page and open some links in new tabs. When i open the new tabs i will be logged in, since i logged in at the start.

When i code this process in selenium using firefox-driver, the new tabs that i open are not logged in. I suspect this is because a new session or user is used for every tab. I suspect this has something to do with cookies.

This is the process i have replicated with selenium:

1. Open login page
2. Login
3. Open (n) tabs
4. Loop through each tabs and interact with content.

My questions is: 
How can i pass cookies, save cookies or use cookies, to make the new tabs that i open in selenium know that i am already logged in since i did that in step 1?

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0):

i tried to replicate your steps but when I open new tabs with below command(using JavaScriptExecutor), i was already logged in. There was no need of saving the cookies.

```
driver.execute_script('''window.open("http://gmail.com","_blank");''')
```

Comment: Hi Sarthak, thank you for your answer. 

I have tried using the code you gave me. I get an exception that says _blank is not recognized.

This is the line of code i tried with: 

`((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("window.open(" + '\u0022' + s + '\u0022' +","+"_blank" +")");`

Important note: I did not use the _blank argument before.

Comment: The exception: 
'ReferenceError: _blank is not defined'